# Obtain (or close to) Identity matrix by multiplying two vectors such as: $D * (C)^H = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, orthonormal

I have an orthonormal vector $C$ of size ($r*n$). I want to pre-multiply the Hermitian transpose of the vector C, by a vector D (size ($r*n$)). The aim is to find vector D such as the result is an identity matrix (size ($n*n$)) or close to an identity matrix.

$D * C^{H} \approx I$.

Please note that $r < n$. Is it possible that the resultant $n*n$ matrix has a higher rank than $r$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The product $AB$ has a rank that's no greater than the smaller of rank $A$ and rank $B$. Hence in your example, the rank of $D*C^H$ will be at most $r < n$. So it'll never be the identity.

When you say "orthonormal vector", I assume you mean "orthonormal matrix"; if we assume that it's the *rows* of your matrix that are orthogonal and are unit vectors, then your best choice for $D$ is simply $D = C$, for then 
$$
D * C^H = \pmatrix{I_r & 0 \\ 
0 & 0}
$$
where the $0$s denote block matrices of size $r \times n-r$, $n-r \times r$, and $n-r \times n -r $, in ordinary reading order, and $I_r$ denotes the $r \times r $ identity matrix.